# Increased height of panel in div click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to increased height of panel in div click.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getheight(this)
{
    document.getElementById('Panel1').style.height="200px";
}
</script>
<div id="flip" onclick="getheight(this)"><div>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Dotted" Height="50px" Width="125px" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
        </asp:Panel>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a server side control , so you won't find an element with ID ='Panel1'.

if you view source the generated html of this page you will find the real ID use it in the

document.getElementById function

you can use document.getElementById('<%=Panel1.ClientID %>'); to automatically insert the

correct ID in your script

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getheight(this)
{
 document.getElementById('Panel1').setAttribute("style", "height:200px;");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Server Side control, you need to set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) = "Static" to prevent .NET from assigning a generated one.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getheight(this)
{
    document.getElementById('Panel1').style.height="200px";
}
</script>
<div id="flip" onclick="getheight(this)">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Dotted" 
       Height="50px" Width="125px" ScrollBars="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</div>
```